# Performance improvement for Innodb - High CPU

Tags: mysql, debian, performance

I have a `dotnet` application that has a high-traffic connection to the MySQL database. It's an application that stores IoT data. It connects to the database **approximately 50 times per second**. In these connections, I run some stored procedures to insert data from IoT which doesn't take a second.

Also, some other queries run and they take a bit of time like 30sec to 2 min something like `ALTER TABLE tablename ENGINE=INNODB;` to get the released space back for usage.

Sometimes the application is locked due to a bottleneck of the *CPU or Memory* and the server is not responding until it kills some processes by itself. I want to resolve this problem and thought the settings of MySQL could be helpful.

Here are details of server and the database.

Database version is `10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1`. 16GB of RAM.

```
htop
  1  [|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||   87.8%]   Tasks: 66, 601 thr; 4 running
  2  [||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||  89.3%]   Load average: 11.41 13.65 15.24
  3  [||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||  89.9%]   Uptime: 14 days, 17:23:29
  4  [|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||   88.2%]
  Mem[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||10.9G/14.3G]
  Swp[                                                                      0K/0K]

  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
 9487 mysql      20   0 13.7G 9504M 19548 S  0.0 64.7  0:00.36 /usr/sbin/mysqld
 9488 mysql      20   0 13.7G 9504M 19548 R  0.0 64.7  0:00.37 /usr/sbin/mysqld
 9489 mysql      20   0 13.7G 9504M 19548 S  0.0 64.7  0:00.36 /usr/sbin/mysqld
 9490 mysql      20   0 13.7G 9504M 19548 S  0.0 64.7  0:00.35 /usr/sbin/mysqld
 9491 mysql      20   0 13.7G 9504M 19548 S  0.0 64.7  0:00.34 /usr/sbin/mysqld
 9492 mysql      20   0 13.7G 9504M 19548 S  0.0 64.7  0:00.35 /usr/sbin/mysqld
 9493 mysql      20   0 13.7G 9504M 19548 S  0.0 64.7  0:00.37 /usr/sbin/mysqld
 9494 mysql      20   0 13.7G 9504M 19548 S  0.0 64.7  0:00.35 /usr/sbin/mysqld
 9495 mysql      20   0 13.7G 9504M 19548 S  0.0 64.7  0:00.37 /usr/sbin/mysqld
 9496 mysql      20   0 13.7G 9504M 19548 S  0.0 64.7  0:00.34 /usr/sbin/mysqld
 9497 mysql      20   0 13.7G 9504M 19548 S  0.0 64.7  0:05.92 /usr/sbin/mysqld
 9498 mysql      20   0 13.7G 9504M 19548 S  0.0 64.7  0:03.98 /usr/sbin/mysqld
20317 root       20   0 21.9G  782M 30716 S 39.3  5.3 11h05:29 dotnet IoTWeb.dll
20343 root       20   0 21.9G  782M 30716 S  6.0  5.3  1h08:16 dotnet IoTWeb.dll
10007 root       20   0 21.9G  782M 30716 S  0.7  5.3  0:02.54 dotnet IoTWeb.dll
10025 root       20   0 21.9G  782M 30716 S  0.7  5.3  0:02.56 dotnet IoTWeb.dll
10313 root       20   0 21.9G  782M 30716 S  0.7  5.3  0:00.87 dotnet IoTWeb.dll
10368 root       20   0 21.9G  782M 30716 S  0.0  5.3  0:01.41 dotnet IoTWeb.dll
10371 root       20   0 21.9G  782M 30716 S  0.7  5.3  0:00.47 dotnet IoTWeb.dll
10372 root       20   0 21.9G  782M 30716 S  0.7  5.3  0:00.54 dotnet IoTWeb.dll
 9722 root       20   0 21.9G  782M 30716 S  2.0  5.3  0:03.79 dotnet IoTWeb.dll
```

```
debian@myvm:~$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 58656
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 58656
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

```
debian@templarivm:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.2G     0  7.2G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.5G  161M  1.3G  11% /run
/dev/sda1        99G   72G   23G  76% / ### SSD
tmpfs           7.2G  4.0K  7.2G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.2G     0  7.2G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1       984G  405G  529G  44% /mnt/sdb1 ### HDD
tmpfs           1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs           1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /run/user/1000
```

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
```

[global status result](https://pastebin.com/Z0qYMp5K)

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
```

[global variables result](https://pastebin.com/8127Jgiv)

MySQL slow query file result is like below.

```
 mysqldumpslow -s t

Reading mysql slow query log from /var/log/mysql/slow_log_file.log
Count: 1  Time=19.89s (19s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows_sent=185.0 (185), Rows_examined=185.0 (185), Rows_affected=0.0 (0), root[root]@92-223-249-84.ip276.fastwebnet.it
  SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `iotemplaribackup`

Count: 10  Time=1.33s (13s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows_sent=0.0 (0), Rows_examined=27344.9 (273449), Rows_affected=232.5 (2325), root[root]@[135.125.216.137]
  CALL SP_InsertMqttPacket('S', 'S', 'S', timestamp('S'), @outParam4, @outParam5, true)

Count: 3  Time=1.14s (3s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows_sent=1.0 (3), Rows_examined=5000.0 (15000), Rows_affected=6667.3 (20002), root[root]@[135.125.216.137]
  CALL SP_RunQuery('S')

Count: 1  Time=2.95s (2s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows_sent=0.0 (0), Rows_examined=0.0 (0), Rows_affected=0.0 (0), root[root]@%
  # Stored_routine: iotemplaribackup.Event_BackupTableCreate
  SET timestamp=N;
  PREPARE stmt FROM  NAME_CONST('S',_binary'S' COLLATE 'S')

Count: 2  Time=1.47s (2s)  Lock=1.48s (2s)  Rows_sent=0.0 (0), Rows_examined=0.0 (0), Rows_affected=0.0 (0), root[root]@%
  # Stored_routine: iotemplaribackup.Event_BackupTableCreate
  SET timestamp=N;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt

Count: 1  Time=2.95s (2s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows_sent=0.0 (0), Rows_examined=0.0 (0), Rows_affected=0.0 (0), root[root]@%
  # Stored_routine: iotemplaribackup.Event_BackupTableCreate
  use iotemplaribackup;
  SET timestamp=N;
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mqttpacket_2105108066`(`data_type_id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL, `data_value` SMALLINT DEFAULT NULL,`inserted_at` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(data_type_id) REFERENCES datatypes(id),PRIMARY KEY(`data_type_id`,`inserted_at`)) ENGINE = InnoDB

Count: 1  Time=2.91s (2s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows_sent=1.0 (1), Rows_examined=1.0 (1), Rows_affected=0.0 (0), root[root]@[135.125.216.137]
  SELECT `d`.`id`, `d`.`customer_id`, `d`.`delete_after`, `d`.`device_name`, `d`.`device_type_id`, `d`.`inserted_time`, `d`.`serial_number`, `d`.`susbscribed`
  FROM `devices` AS `d`
  WHERE `d`.`id` = N
  LIMIT N;
  SET timestamp=N;
  CALL SP_InsertMqttPacket('S', 'S', 'S', timestamp('S'), @outParam4, @outParam5, true)

Count: 1  Time=1.08s (1s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows_sent=337882.0 (337882), Rows_examined=675764.0 (675764), Rows_affected=0.0 (0), root[root]@[135.125.216.137]
  CALL SP_GetChartMQTTPackets('S', 'S', timestamp('S'), timestamp('S'))

Count: 1  Time=0.00s (0s)  Lock=2.95s (2s)  Rows_sent=0.0 (0), Rows_examined=0.0 (0), Rows_affected=0.0 (0), root[root]@%
  # Stored_routine: iotemplaribackup.Event_BackupTableCreate
  SET timestamp=N;
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mqttpacket_2105108066`(`data_type_id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL, `data_value` SMALLINT DEFAULT NULL,`inserted_at` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(data_type_id) REFERENCES datatypes(id),PRIMARY KEY(`data_type_id`,`inserted_at`)) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

**EDIT**: This had to be in the begging indeed. In order to store this IoT data and select it fastly, I implemented a table-per-IoT logic with around 150 IoT. Since the data frequency is so high I had to choose this. While doing this (accepting that is bad engineering) I created a backup database on another disk in order to keep the live DB to store only recent weeks of data such as 2-3 weeks only.

Any suggestion on how can I improve the performance regarding this? I am open to any suggestion, I can change the whole design as well.

Comment: Gotta see the queries that were running.  If you have no clues, use the [_SlowLog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog)

Comment: The GLOBAL STATUS is almost useless because it covers only about 20 minutes;  Grab it again after a day or so.

Comment: How much RAM?..

Comment: @RickJames It is 16GB of RAM and I've uploaded a new `GLOBAL STATUS` result. Slowlog file wasn't filled up for some reason I couldn't get it. I have a general log file created instead, if it's helpful I can share it.

Comment: @RickJames I made it now. The file was immediately filled with my threads of insert queries. I updated the question. My other problem is that I need a backup of the existing database on another disk which is HDD and slower than the main disk. As a silly solution I made to insert the same data twice; one to the main db, other to backup. Do you have a suggestion for that? I need to keep the main disk with low storage since it's limited. Therefore, I clean the data older than 2-3weeks and run `ALTER TABLE tablename ENGINE=INNODB;` which takes around 2 minutes per table. I have table per IoT logic

Comment: @TaylanYuksel  The Jul 5, 2022 Show Global Status was captured at 200 seconds of uptime.  Could you post new one after minimum of 86400 seconds (1 day - 10 days would be better - whatever you can get without a stop/start).

Comment: @WilsonHauck here is a longer [GLOBAL STATUS](https://pastebin.com/eW5BEnEM) but the uptime is low **14727**. Since the server is crashing everyday because of this issue, I restart it...

Comment: Unfortunately, we need to see the SQL inside those 'slow' Procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your OS and my.cnf [mysqld] section

For your OS,
ulimit -n 32768  # to increase Open Files limit for your load + other apps needs

For this to persist across OS stop/start this url is a basic guide for similar system.
https://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/increase-ulimit-and-file-descriptors-limit/
use 32768 where the examples has 500000, please.

For your my.cnf [mysqld] section,

```
read_rnd_buffer_size=32K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 413,713
read_buffer_size=256K  # from 128K to reuce handler_read_next RPS of 2,197
innodb_log_file_size=5G  # from 256M to support ~ 1 hr before rotation to new log
innodb_log_buffer_size=3G  # from 128NM to support ~ 30 min before write to media
innodb_flush_neighbors=2  # from 1 to flush rows in 1 sweep to current extent and this will keep dirty pages minimized.
innodb_thread_concurrency=4  # from 0 to allow other apps access when needed
```

Observations:
Your strategy for prepare and execute stored procedures should be reviewed.
Normally one prepare will support many executes before needing another prepare.
Your strategy for execute and close (or dealloc) stored procedures should be reviewed.
We find best success is when execute is followed by close to release resources needed to complete stored procedure execution.  You have many dangling executes.
During the 4 hours of uptime, 355,271 com_create_table events occurred.  What can you do with these newly created tables?
Select_scan count of 37,017,333 in 4 hours (2,514 RPS) tells me you really need indexes to avoid table scans at this rate.

Please view profile for contact info and free Utility Scripts and get in touch by email to review any details.

Comment: I'll apply your feedback and revert you. About the table creations, I realized a bad engineering practice I was doing is in every insert checking whether the table exists or not which is like `CREATE <MYTABLE> IF NOT EXISTS...`. So, I moved it to somewhere else to check only once.

Comment: I applied all your suggestions to my system. They improved the performance significantly! Each core's load is reduced from ~80% to ~20%. Removing unnecessary `create table` queries was also so helpful.

Comment: So performance tuning DOES WORK, when attempted and with appropriate guidance.  Congratulations.  Looking forward to your email when time permits.

Comment: is it possible that you to give feedback about this server as well? I have the same application running. In fact, I switched to a better server.
[SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES](https://pastebin.com/ccKiqE8P)
[SHOW GLOBAL STATUS](https://pastebin.com/1jBgkhVW)
[Server Specs](https://pastebin.com/qrybqY75)

Comment: @Taylan-Yuksel  What country and time zone are you in?  Please view profile for contact info and get in touch by email or Skype TALK - my Skype ID is  wlhauck@aol.com  in Birmingham,AL  USA GMT -5 hrs.  Thanks

Comment: I am in Italy GMT+2 ROME. I am contacting you by skype. Regards.

Answer (score 3):

I hear multiple questions:

- How to ingest 50+ rows per second onto a slow HDD from IoT.
- How to migrate "old" data off the SSD onto HDD.
- How to deal with lots of tables (one per IoT).

I'm not sure if those are really your goals, but let me start with them.

**Batch Insertion** (or not)

For high speed ingestion, it is best to collect multiple rows, then insert them in a single INSERT statement.  A 100-row batch will Insert about 10 times as fast as 100 single-row Inserts.

But that may not be practical if the inserts are coming in separately.  And especially if they are going to separate tables.

Well, "table-per-IoT" is bad for many reasons; I will cover that below.

Inserting a row in the "fact" table of a Data Warehouse may involve normalization, index updating, etc.  This adds to the mere 50 rows per second.  So, I recommend collecting, say, all the data from a second into a temp table (one at a time, no indexes, no normalization) and then blast them from that table into the 'real' Fact table(s) and Summary tables.  I discuss this in [*High speed ingestion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table)

**Archiving old data**

By Partitioning by date, a chunk of a table can be removed and copied to another table or disk or machine.  This involves having a single table for all the data, but have it `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(...))`.  Then an 'old' partition can be "transported" to another location.  This involves some special commands to remove it from the existing Partitioned table, etc.  See [*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) -- both the time-series discussion and the transportable tablespaces.

**Single table**

Notice that I have twice referred to the table structure.  For IoT (or similar Data Warehouse applications), I recommend these characteristics:

- Single Fact table
- Index it thus:  `PRIMARY KEY(sensor, datetime)`, plus very few other indexes.  Having the `sensor` first in the PK has benefits for many of the likely queries.
- Summary tables for counting, averaging, summing, etc the data over each hour or day.  Such table(s) will be much faster for reports, graphs, etc.  Furthermore, they can easily have more indexes -- that are cheap to have on the Summary tables in place of being costly on the Fact table.
- Normalized -- Any long strings that repeat a lot are put into lookup tables, not stored in the Fact table.  Instead, a `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (2 bytes, range 0..64K) or other sized INT is used in its place.  The Summary tables may want to 'denormalize'.  The Batch insert can "batch-normalize" for added efficiency.
- [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)
- [*Sensor Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_sensor) [Not finished]

Comment: Appreciate your feedback a lot! I see your guide _Sensor Tables_ exactly points out my problems. I'll go with mentioned designed _Plan A_ from the link. But I'll not be able to use `Summary Table` since the requests I receive are always to draw a chart, not a summary. PS. suggesting not to use `REPLACE INTO` was also very helpful in the guide.  Cheers!

Comment: If you are charting for a year, but have sensor data by the second, that is about 30 million datapoints in the chart!.  If you have daily summaries, 365 points would be "as good" for drawing the chart.  The summary tables could have min-max, thereby allowing something like candlesticks.

Comment: Once IODKU (upsert) was added to MySQL, `REPLACE` become virtually useless.

Comment: Requests are usually by 1-3-7 days, a maximum of a month. But within ~20 different types of sensors at the same time. So, maybe the same amount of records with a year and a single sensor. In this chart, users look at the chart closer from the general view.  For example they see a time series that the sensors look like sending awkward values. Then, zoom more into the chart and see it 10 seconds manner.

Comment: A question about the `IODKU` that I don't have `id` PK. The PK is (`sensor_id,dt`). So, should I write it like `INSERT INTO sensors (sensor_id, dt, value) VALUES(1,'some_date',0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  ` update what here? (In case a sensor repeats with the same *timestamp*.)

Comment: @TaylanYuksel - a Summary table based on "hour" might be best.  If only 24 points is too few for 1-day, then maybe 10-minute or 1-minute summaries.  (How often is each sensor reporting?)

Comment: Each IoT reports ~50 different sensors every 5 seconds.

Comment: I don't have a good answer for "anomalies".  In monitoring Covid data, occasionally the data would have a negative number of new cases for the day.  Or suddenly 20 times as many cases as any surrounding day.  It is mathematically hard to discover such -- in order to throw them out.  Or at least not have an ugly spike in a chart that messes with things.

Comment: IODKU -- Yes.  However.are you expecting the same sensor to send the same data for the same time?  Of this is the issue, simply use `INSERT IGNORE`.  If it might send a _corrected_ 'value', then IODKU is needed.  I like IODKU for upserting into the Summary table.  (Unless I choose to, say, batch insert a day's worth after midnight.)

Comment: "every 5 seconds" -- 1-minute summary would be OK.  That is a 12x shrinkage of number of rows.  (I like to shoot for at least 10x.)  A 1-day chart would have 1440 data points--OK.  But 7 days is getting a bit bulky.

Comment: Another possibility -- collect data for a minute, including start, min, max, end, avg.  Then throw away the 5-second data.  Poof, you have nearly all the data, but with 1/12th as many rows!  (Yeah, a few extra columns, so more line 1/6th.)  Would that eliminate the need for your two disk drives??

Comment: @TaylanYuksel - (Thanks for this discussion; it gives me ideas on what I need to add to my Sensors blog.)

Comment: You mentioned "Plan A".  It sounds like you don't need a `location` column.  "A" was based on a consistent set of sensors (temp, wind, etc) at multiple "weather" locations.

Comment: Storing this summary will also increase the disk usage around that much but it can be handled with a bigger space! So, my final table design would be `sensors (sensor_id, machine_id, dt, value)` would insert (5sec)12 x 50sensor x 200 machine = 120000 rows per minute.

Comment: It's my pleasure to have a chance to hear solutions from an expert like you. I evaluate your Plan A for my application tho. So, the location here would be my `machine_id` column.

Comment: 2K rows/second is probably possible on SSD.  But we should work on getting that down some.

Comment: One machine delivers 50 numbers in a single HTTP request, correct?  Would it make sense to have a 50-column (plus overhead) row?  That drops it to a mere 40 Inserts/second.  This is very possible, even after adding summary table overhead, etc.

Comment: Yes, they deliver it in a single request. But I can't really go with 50-column since tomorrow somebody may want to add a new sensor as well. (this is very possible to happen even every month) and some machines have different types of sensors.

Comment: Are you implying that different machines (even today) have a different number of sensors?  And the record that comes from each different model of machine needs a different parser?  And you have PHP (or Java or whatever) code to deal with this, before hitting the database?

Comment: Thinking out-of-the-box...  How about a hybrid approach?  The single string with ~50 values for one machine is stored in the Fact table of 1 row per machine per 5 seconds.  Meanwhile, it is parsed and summarized into a Summary table as 1 row per minute per sensor per machine.  That way, the total is only a few Inserts/sec (a few hundred per minute).

Comment: Oh, I left out a note -- when storing the 50+ sensors in a row, store it either in the original format or in JSON.  This allows for new sensors in the future (and for variety in the 1000 machines today).

Comment: The entire solution is developed on `dotnet core`. The solution covers an MQTT handler application called `IoT bridge` and a web application `asp.net Razor`. I meant about a machine is a physical machine, an air conditioner. That sends many different sets of values and I have different types (`machine_type_id`) of them. Meanwhile, they are planted in many different locations where I manage them with the `machine_id` column. So, I receive simultaneously ~50 types of data from every machine.

Comment: To help me understand, can you show me (or point me at a URL) the format of the raw data coming from the air conditioner (or whatever).

Comment: [here is a link](https://pastebin.com/0pf8UgLf) shows the sensor data and topic. The topic covers the machine's serial number. So, I parse it from there. Every sensor type has an `id` and some other columns of information about them.

Comment: JSON -- I would be tempted to pull out `ts` into a separate column, then save`d` as the JSON.  (Do check that your version of MySQL correctly handles the "T" in that timestamp.)

Comment: To decrease the disk space usage and draw the chart request faster, is it better to have this `d` with `id` instead of the sensor name? It is also another workload for the database to get the `id` of these sensor names... I want to keep my `DataTypes` table. What is your suggestion?

Comment: Assuming that `d` comes in every 5 seconds and the smallest chart is for 1 day, 1-minute summaries is all that is needed.  That is the summary table would have (machine_id, sensor_name, ts_to_minute, value).  That is ~50 rows per _minute_.  Value would be the average over the minute.  (Maybe you also need high/low?)  Sensor_name might need to be sensor_id, depending on whether some machines have long-winded names.

Comment: I am still not very well convinced about the summary table(*candlestick*). It can be an inefficient solution for the users since they want to zoom in and see where the machine sent an awkward value. So, even 5 seconds of detail may be required to distinguish..  I'll prose it and will think about all your suggestions. Storing JSON is also a problem while drawing a chart since they can ask to draw 10 sensor types out of these ~50 sensors. So, it would be very much extra work to separate it during the request.

Comment: For the specific details (eg, for zooming in and investigating anomalies, the JSON is easy enough to parse.  Here, I am thinking not necessarily of a zoomed in chart, but a tabular array of the raw data.  One bad value is sometimes accompanied by other bad values; looking at the raw data may be the best for all concerned.  (And, yes, my blog needs to have a section or two on anamolies and "events".  Example: the temp shoots up (and stays high) because the fan belt breaks (fan_speed drops to 0).)

Answer (score 1):

Analysis of GLOBAL STATUS and VARIABLES:

**Observations:**

- Version: 10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1
- 16 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 04:05:27; some GLOBAL STATUS values may not be meaningful yet.
- 1.58e+4 Queries/sec : 335 Questions/sec

**The More Important Issues:**

Some metrics below suggest more RAM and a bigger innodb_buffer_pool_size would help.

See if you can reuse prepared statements rather than closing 98% of them.

Suggested changes:

```
key_buffer_size = 30M  -- lowered since MyISAM is not being used
innodb_io_capacity = 1000  -- if disk is SSD
innodb_flush_neighbors = 0  -- if SSD
innodb_log_file_size -- Caution; this is complex to change
innodb_change_buffer_max_size = 25 -- unless you have a reason for "50"
query_cache_type = OFF
query_cache_size = 0
```

**Details and other observations:**

`( Key_blocks_used * 1024 / key_buffer_size ) = 2 * 1024 / 128M = 0.00%` -- Percent of key_buffer used. High-water-mark.
-- Lower key_buffer_size (now 134217728) to avoid unnecessary memory usage.

`( Key_reads + Key_writes + Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written + Innodb_dblwr_writes + Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed ) = (2 + 0 + 342390 + 3638550 + 295730 + 3638550) / 14727 = 537 /sec` -- IOPs?
-- If the hardware can handle it, set innodb_io_capacity (now 500) to about this value.

`( ( Key_reads + Key_writes + Innodb_pages_read + Innodb_pages_written + Innodb_dblwr_writes + Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed ) / innodb_io_capacity / Uptime ) = ( 2 + 0 + 342390 + 3638550 + 295730 + 3638550 ) / 500 / 14727 = 107.5%` -- This *may* be a metric indicating what innodb_io_capacity is set reasonably.
-- Increase innodb_io_capacity (now 500) if the hardware can handle it.

`( innodb_io_capacity_max / innodb_io_capacity ) = 2,000 / 500 = 4` -- Capacity: max/plain
-- Recommend 2. Max should be about equal to the IOPs your I/O subsystem can handle. (If the drive type is unknown 2000/200 may be a reasonable pair.)

`( (Innodb_buffer_pool_reads + Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed) ) = ((331721 + 3638550) ) / 14727 = 269 /sec` -- InnoDB I/O
-- Increase innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 10737418240)?

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed ) = ((331721 + 3638550) ) / 14727 = 247 /sec` -- Writes (flushes)
-- Increase innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 10737418240)?

`( innodb_change_buffer_max_size ) = 50` -- Percent of buffer_pool that is used for "change buffer" -- a write cache for index changes.
-- This should not be so small that it hampers delaying writes, not so large that it interferes with reads.

`( Innodb_os_log_written ) = 1612644 /sec` -- This is an indicator of how busy InnoDB is.
-- Very idle or very busy InnoDB.

`( innodb_log_buffer_size ) = 128M` -- Suggest 2MB-64MB, and at least as big as biggest blob set in transactions.
-- Adjust innodb_log_buffer_size (now 134217728).

`( innodb_log_buffer_size / innodb_log_file_size ) = 128M / 256M = 50.0%` -- Buffer is in RAM; file is on disk.
-- The buffer_size should be smaller and/or the file_size should be larger.

`( Innodb_log_writes ) = 932 /sec`

`( Innodb_os_log_written / (Uptime / 3600) / innodb_log_files_in_group / innodb_log_file_size ) = 23,749,420,544 / (14727 / 3600) / 2 / 256M = 10.8` -- Ratio
-- (see minutes)

`( Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written ) = 14,727 / 60 * 256M / 23749420544 = 2.77` -- Minutes between InnoDB log rotations Beginning with 5.6.8, innodb_log_file_size can be changed dynamically; I don't know about MariaDB. Be sure to also change my.cnf
-- (The recommendation of 60 minutes between rotations is somewhat arbitrary.) Adjust innodb_log_file_size (now 268435456). (Cannot change in AWS.)

`( Innodb_row_lock_waits ) = 0.34 /sec` -- How often there is a delay in getting a row lock.
-- May be caused by complex queries that could be optimized.

`( Innodb_dblwr_writes ) = 20 /sec` -- "Doublewrite buffer" writes to disk. "Doublewrites" are a reliability feature. Some newer versions / configurations don't need them.
-- (Symptom of other issues)

`( innodb_flush_neighbors ) = innodb_flush_neighbors = 1` -- A minor optimization when writing blocks to disk.
-- Use 0 for SSD drives; 1 for HDD.

`( innodb_adaptive_hash_index ) = innodb_adaptive_hash_index = ON` -- Whether to use the adapative hash (AHI).
-- ON for mostly readonly; OFF for DDL-heavy

`( innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit ) = 1` -- 1 = secure; 2 = faster
-- (You decide) Use 1, along with sync_binlog (now 0)=1 for the greatest level of fault tolerance. 0 is best for speed. 2 is a compromise between 0 and 1.

`( innodb_adaptive_hash_index ) = innodb_adaptive_hash_index = ON` -- Usually should be ON.
-- There are cases where OFF is better. See also innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts (now 8) (after 5.7.9) and innodb_adaptive_hash_index_partitions (MariaDB and Percona). ON has been implicated in rare crashes (bug 73890). 10.5.0 decided to default OFF.

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( innodb_ft_result_cache_limit ) = 2,000,000,000 / 16384M = 11.6%` -- Byte limit on FULLTEXT resultset. (It grows as needed.)
-- Lower the setting.

`( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile (now ON) = ON is a potential security issue

`( Qcache_not_cached ) = (Innodb_deadlocks) / 14727 = 49 /sec` -- SQL_CACHE attempted, but ignored
-- Rethink caching; tune qcache

`( Qcache_hits / (Qcache_hits + Com_select) ) = 461,409 / (461409 + 38022537) = 1.2%` -- Hit ratio -- SELECTs that used QC
-- Consider turning off the query cache.

`( (query_cache_size - Qcache_free_memory) / Qcache_queries_in_cache / query_alloc_block_size ) = (16M - 13121952) / 3138 / 16384 = 0.0711` -- query_alloc_block_size vs formula
-- Adjust query_alloc_block_size (now 16384)

`( Queries ) = (181705 - 3138) / 14727 = 15824 /sec` -- Queries (including inside SP)
-- >3000 *may* be stressing server

`( (Queries-Questions)/Queries ) = (233052549-4930886)/233052549 = 97.9%` -- Fraction of queries that are inside Stored Routines.
-- (Not bad if high; but it impacts the validity of some other conclusions.)

`( Com_insert + Com_delete + Com_delete_multi + Com_replace + Com_update + Com_update_multi ) = (18326112 + 3121 + 0 + 0 + 220 + 0) / 14727 = 1244 /sec` -- writes/sec
-- 50 writes/sec + log flushes will probably max out I/O write capacity of normal drives

`( Com_stmt_prepare - Com_stmt_close ) = 18,687,518 - 18332247 = 355,271` -- How many prepared statements have not been closed.
-- CLOSE prepared statements

`( Com_stmt_close / Com_stmt_prepare ) = 18,332,247 / 18687518 = 98.1%` -- Prepared statements should be Closed.
-- Check whether all Prepared statements are "Closed".

`( Com_admin_commands ) = 121 /sec`
-- Why so many DDL statements?

`( binlog_format ) = binlog_format = MIXED` -- STATEMENT/ROW/MIXED.
-- ROW is preferred by 5.7 (10.3)

`( slow_query_log ) = slow_query_log = OFF` -- Whether to log slow queries. (5.1.12)

`( long_query_time ) = 10` -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query.
-- Suggest 2

`( back_log ) = 80` -- (Autosized as of 5.6.6; based on max_connections)
-- Raising to min(150, max_connections (now 151)) may help when doing lots of connections.

`( thread_cache_size / Max_used_connections ) = 151 / 74 = 204.1%`
-- There is no advantage in having the thread cache bigger than your likely number of connections. Wasting space is the disadvantage.

`( thread_pool_max_threads ) = 65,536` -- One of many settings for MariaDB's thread pooling
-- Lower the value.

**Abnormally small:**

```
((query_cache_size - Qcache_free_memory) /
      Qcache_queries_in_cache) / query_cache_min_res_unit = 0.284
(query_cache_size - Qcache_free_memory) /
      Qcache_queries_in_cache = 1,164
(query_cache_size - Qcache_free_memory) /
      Qcache_queries_in_cache = 1,164
Acl_database_grants = 0
Acl_users = 2
Aria_pagecache_read_requests = 17 /HR
Aria_pagecache_reads = 1.2 /HR
Aria_pagecache_write_requests = 3.4 /HR
Com_show_fields = 0
Handler_read_first = 2 /HR
Handler_read_rnd = 5.6 /HR
Handler_tmp_write = 0.56 /sec
Rows_tmp_read = 0.56 /sec
Select_range / Com_select = 0.00%
Sort_priority_queue_sorts = 0.24 /HR
Sort_rows = 64 /HR
Sort_scan = 0.98 /HR
innodb_lru_scan_depth / innodb_io_capacity = 0.2
```

**Abnormally large:**

```
Com_begin = 24 /sec
Com_call_procedure = 25 /sec
Com_create_table = 24 /sec
Com_dealloc_sql = 25 /sec
Com_execute_sql = 1268 /sec
Com_insert = 1244 /sec
Com_insert_select = 0.21 /sec
Com_insert_select + Com_replace_select = 0.21 /sec
Com_prepare_sql = 1268 /sec
Com_select = 2581 /sec
Com_stmt_close = 1244 /sec
Com_stmt_execute = 1268 /sec
Com_stmt_prepare = 1268 /sec
Empty_queries = 2517 /sec
Feature_json = 24 /sec
Feature_subquery = 2488 /sec
Handler_commit = 5038 /sec
Handler_commit/Questions = 1504.9%
Handler_delete = 1059 /sec
Handler_read_rnd_next / Handler_read_rnd = 2.65e+8
Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests = 13333 /sec
Innodb_data_fsyncs = 1020 /sec
Innodb_data_writes = 1200 /sec
Innodb_data_writes - Innodb_log_writes - Innodb_dblwr_writes = 247 /sec
Innodb_data_written = 9708271 /sec
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written = 247 /sec
Innodb_log_write_requests = 2229 /sec
Innodb_os_log_fsyncs = 933 /sec
Innodb_pages_created = 16 /sec
Innodb_pages_written = 247 /sec
Innodb_rows_deleted = 1059 /sec
Innodb_rows_deleted + Innodb_rows_inserted = 2318 /sec
Innodb_rows_inserted = 1258 /sec
Prepared_stmt_count = 20
Table_open_cache_hits = 6285 /sec
Tc_log_page_size = 4,096
innodb_background_scrub_data_check_interval = 0.24 /sec
innodb_background_scrub_data_interval = 41 /sec
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
Slave_heartbeat_period = 0
Slave_received_heartbeats = 0
aria_recover_options = BACKUP,QUICK
event_scheduler = ON
ft_boolean_syntax = + -><()~*:&
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
myisam_stats_method = NULLS_UNEQUAL
old_alter_table = DEFAULT
```